# CSS/Javascript dynamic gradient or shadow

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, gradient, shadow

I'm using these rules:

```
.log-widget-alexa{ background: #001C48;}
.log-widget-altervista{ background: #FFE852;}
.log-widget-amazon{ background: #000000;}
.log-widget-aol{ background: #0060A3;}
etc ..
```

I would like to use only 1 more class to add an inset darken shadow or gradient color to emboss the widgets with same darken background.

Is it possible with some CSS/JavaScript/jQuery tricks?

I mean if i have background:#666; I would like to add a simple gradient/shadow in #555 for example (little beat darken from the starter background color in this case = #666)

I would like to set some css trick rather than manually with box-shadow or background-image gradient :/ because i have thousands of these rules in my CSS.

Comment: You mean you want the shadow to somehow "adapt" to the background?

Comment: i mean somenthing like SASS lighter($background_element, -5%)

Comment: @Abody97 if is there a way to exclude SASS is better

Comment: i think you catched the question anyway

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible with pure CSS. You need Javascript for that. Select all your elements, get the background color with `.css()`, compute the seconds color, and then with `.css()` apply the gradient accordingly.

Comment: @ispuk I'm writing this on my mobile but when I'm in reach of a PC I will show it to you.

Comment: Stupif phone sending this twice... You can try out the following for a start: stackoverflow.com/questions/6016988/applying-css3-gradients-with-jquery stackoverflow.com/questions/638948/background-color-hex-to-javascript-variable-jquery